# When playing mkv movie by vlc media player, sometimes I only get the video not the audio

Tags: 14.04, sound, vlc, mkv

I have VLC media player installed on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

The problem is when I play movies that are in `.mkv` format using VLC it sometimes cannot play the sound of the movie and I only see the video. This problem occurs in the middle of the movie when I click on the progress bar to go forward or backward.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 64 bit

Comment: mkv is just a container (mkv itself shouldn't cause any trouble), what matters is codec, which you can check in VLC ---> Tools --> Codec information...when your movie is being played

Comment: Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)       and :   Decoded format: Planar 4:2:0 YUV                  ** ok what should I do now?

Comment: check this: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=79953 and this: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=42328

Answer (score 11):

If VLC shows following error:

> No suitable decoder module VLC does not support the audio or video format hevc. Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.

Then try to install libde265 via PPA.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:strukturag/libde265 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

VLC should now play these media files after installation has been completed successfully.

Comment: the upgrade part is dangerous and one need to be sure what he/she is doing. you might upgrade some dependencies and get yourself into trouble !